# Django seems to be caching datetime.now()

Tags: python, django, caching, datetime

I have a model that looks like this:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    ...
    publish_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    ...
```

And a manager that looks like this:

```
from datetime import datetime

class ItemManager(Manager):
    def published(self):
        return self.get_query_set().filter(publish_date__lte=datetime.now()
```

And a view that looks like this:

```
class ItemArchive(ArchiveIndexView):
    queryset = Item.objects.published()
    date_field = 'publish_date'
```

The idea being that I can call `Item.objects.published()` and get a queryset of all published `Items`.

The problem is that Django seems to be executing the `datetime.now()` call in the manager when the server is started and then caching that value. So if today is May 24th, and I created an `Item` with a publish date of May 23rd, and started the server on May 22nd, that May 23rd item will not show up in the `ItemArchive` view. As soon as I restart Apache, the May 23rd item shows up in the view correctly.

How can I force Django to execute `datetime.now()` every time the manager is called?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe this is caused by your view defining `queryset = Item.objects.published()` as a class variable. This line will be executed once, when your `ItemArchive` class is initially imported. You should move that line into a method where it will be executed each time a view is called.

Comment: Yes. Or, define a separate PublishedManager, which overrides `get_query_set`. This will be lazy, whereas your `published` method is not.

Comment: It would certainly work. The best technique would depend on the context. If it really makes sense to have `queryset` as a class variable, then Daniel's suggestion would be best. However, your code may be more readable if you just directly call `Item.objects.published()` wherever you are currently using `queryset`.

Comment: Thanks to you both! It took me a little tinkering, but both solutions make sense. I think dgel's is more appropriate in my context.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use the `queryset` class variable, and override `get_queryset` instead. In general, I think `queryset` is a bit of a red herring. If you just specify `model` instead, Django automatically sets the queryset to `self.model.objects.all()`. If you need any filtering, 99 times out of 100 you'll need to override `get_queryset` to be thread-safe. Try the following instead.

```
class ItemArchive(ArchiveIndexView):
    model = Item
    date_field = 'publish_date'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(ItemArchive, self).get_queryset().published()
```

Answer (score 0):

First, just use `models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)`

**Edited:**

Second, use `get_queryset` method:

```
class ItemArchive(ArchiveIndexView):
    date_field = 'publish_date'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Item.objects.published()
```

Comment: I don't want to use `auto_now_add` because I want to give users the option of editing the publication date. Overwriting `get_queryset` is what dgel suggested in his answer. I think that's the solution. Thanks!