# Using datetime.now() in Django view

Tags: python, django, datetime, gunicorn

**The Code**

I am using datetime.now() as part of a filter in a Django view as follows:

```
def get_now():
    return timezone.now()

class BulletinListView(ListView):
    model = Announcement
    template_name = 'newswire/home.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BulletinListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        try:
            published_announcements = Announcement.objects.filter(publish_start_date__lte=get_now(), publish_end_date__gte=get_now()).filter(hidden=False, under_review=False).extra(order_by=['-publish_start_date', 'publish_end_date'])
        except Announcement.DoesNotExist:
            published_announcements = None

        if published_announcements is not None:
            context['announcements'] = published_announcements
            max_print_annoucements = int(config.MAX_PRINT_ANNOUCEMENTS)
            context['announcements_print'] = published_announcements[
                :max_print_annoucements]
            context['more_annoucements_online_count'] = published_announcements.count() - max_print_annoucements

        return context
```

**Edit:** Managed to update and include more code

It works correctly and gets announcements that are supposed to be published and are not hidden or under review according to to the date supplied by `datetime.now()`

**The Problem**

I use `datetime.datetime.now()` to filter out old announcements but I realised after a day in the production environment that `datetime.datetime.now()` is being evaluated only when the server starts and the value does not update each time the view is called which results in the wrong data being filtered when the next day comes around. This is also affecting another function which retrieves upcoming birthdays in the next 7 days.

**Things I Read and Tried**

I have seen a number of questions about using the callable `datetime.now` instead of `datetime.now()` but only in the context of setting default values in the model.

I have defined a function as follows thinking it would force `datetime.now` to be evaluated again but it does not seem to work.

```
def get_now():
    return timezone.now())
```

When I pass the date i get to the context to see what I'm getting, I see that the date and time doesn't advance past the time I deploy the server.

I have seen a number of examples of using datetime.now() in the view but none run into this issue.

I suspect I have never seen this in development because I run the development gunicorn server with the --reload option and `datetime.now()` is constantly evaluated when I save changes and the server restarts.

[This problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10741201/django-seems-to-be-caching-datetime-now) seems to be similar but I'm not sure how it is similar/different to my situation

**Context:**

I am writing a Django application and my development and production environments are implemented using docker and the application run behind an nginx proxy

```
/usr/local/bin/gunicorn app.wsgi:application -w 2 -b :8000
```

Comment: "but I realised after a day in the production environment that datetime.datetime.now() is being evaluated only when the server starts and the value does not update each time the view is called" Not so. You probably have a messed up caching setup

Comment: As an aside, servers that may be handling requests across time zones should likely be using universal time via `datetime.utcnow()`.

Comment: @e4c5 I shall give the stack a look over again for any caching but from my Django settings file I haven't defined any caching.

Comment: @tdelaney thanks for pointing that out, I realised that too after searching for answers for my problem and am looking to move things over. I will use `datetime.utcnow()` eventually and incidentally I'm working on this project which is in another timezone! So the timezone thing is kinda real to me. I'm figuring it out slowly, first Django project! First real world application with real user feedback.

Comment: Try opening in different browsers(I recommend using incognito mode) and see if you get different results. View should work. It can be caching on browser or somewhere on intermediate network hardware.

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev I tried safari and chrome in incognito. I'm afraid it's a server side issue.

Comment: As an aside, `filter()` never raises `DoesNotExist` - so you don't need the try/except block.

Answer (score 0):

> the value does not update each time the view is called which results
>   in the wrong data being filtered when the next day comes around

You have to decide which "next day" are you talking about? Is it:

1. The next day for the user visiting your site.
2. The next day for you, visiting the site.
3. The next day for the timezone that is set on the server.

Each one of these will end up in a "wrong" result, when in fact nothing is actually wrong with the code.

This is because your code is naive when it comes to timezones. It basically ignores timezones completely.

This is a complicated topic, and django has a [complete section of the manual](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/timezones/) dedicated to dealing with timezones. I suggest reading it once or twice as there are many ways timezones can affect your site.

Finally, you can clean up your code a bit, like this:

```
try:
   max_print_annoucements = int(config.MAX_PRINT_ANNOUCEMENTS)
except ValueError:
   max_print_announcements = 0

published_announcements = Announcement.objects.filter(publish_start_date__lte=get_now(),
                                                      publish_end_date__gte=get_now())
                                              .filter(hidden=False, under_review=False)
                                              .extra(order_by=['-publish_start_date',
                                                               'publish_end_date'])

context['announcements'] = published_announcements
context['announcements_print'] = published_announcements[:max_print_annoucements]
context['more_annoucements_online_count'] = abs(published_announcements.count() - max_print_annoucements)
```

Comment: "When the next day comes around" literally means when I load the page the next day, the datetime.now() should really be reflecting the current date/time but it still is the time I deployed the containers into production.
I actually don't think the issue has anything to do with timezones at all. I did `context['now'] = get_now()` and displayed it in the template using `{{ now|date:"l g:i A, j F o" }}` and it shows that the date/time is basically just stuck at the time I deployed the server in production. Is there something wrong with doing that?

Comment: Unless the server is running your local computer, chances are your next day and the next day for the server are different.